# How to optimize mysql group by with order by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am currently experiencing an extremely slow query when using group by and order by.  I have an inclination that the indexes are not being used because group by is on a separate column then order by

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55f53/1)

Foo Table Structure

```
id -> pk (indexed)
bar_id -> foreign key (indexed)
data -> varchar 
created_at -> timestamp (indexed)
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo GROUP BY bar_id ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I am basically trying to get the most recent records for each bar_id. However this is taking up to 11 seconds to finish.  Is there a better way to do this type of query?

Comment: A *better* way? This isn't even *a way*!

Comment: @Matt You get not the most recent row but indeterminate values per group, I cite _The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate_ (see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: @VMai So is there a new query I can use to achieve this?

Comment: I doubt this will actually perform faster but try grouping after order by... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55f53/4 .... it ran in less than 2 seconds on the sqlfiddle

Comment: I said why I thought it was off-topic. And what about the bit where I was shouting?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Did not work.

Comment: @Strawberry updated sqlFiddle with expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    98304 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

SELECT x.* 
  FROM foo x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT bar_id
            , MAX(created_at) max_created_at 
         FROM foo
        GROUP
           BY bar_id
     ) y
    ON y.bar_id = x.bar_id 
   AND y.max_created_at = x.created_at;

531 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Note: I've modified your schema slightly.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6296/2

Comment: why not just use IN(select max(created_at) from foo)?

Comment: @JohnRuddell 1. Because performance is an issue apprarently. And 2. what if the max(created_at) value of one bar_id corresponds to a non-max(created_at) value of another bar_id.

Comment: I had already thought about that... but since the OP is saying his date is the same (in his expected results) it seems like that would be more simple.. or even using a user-defined variable equal to the max date

Comment: also this query will return more than one row for a bar_id when the max date is in the table more than once

Comment: So would using `IN (subquery...)` syntax. But `IN (subquery...)` results in a correlated sub query which is likely to be slow.

Comment: @JohnRuddell But not for a different id. I think it reasonable to assume (although not made explicit) that there is an implied UNIQUE KEY constraint on (bar_id,created_at). John, you're welcome to argue the toss, but this (the uncorellated subquery method) IS generally considered to be the fastest documented solution. Show me different and I'll convert.

Comment: I want to point out this table has about 200,000 rows.  I am still experiencing load times of over 15 seconds with this query.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, those columns were already indexed i just didn't put it in the fiddle. I am still reaching rather high load times of about 4 seconds.

Comment: In that case can you provide the actual DDLs and the actual EXPLAIN?As you can see, it takes less than a second on my data set